# Pseudocode Flowchart

Tags: pseudocode

So for my summer task for A Level Computer Science before starting Year 12, I have been given a task where I have to convert a flowchart into pseudocode.

This is the task: https://www.leggott.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/SummerTask-JLC-Programming.pdf

So far I have got this:

```
// checking the patient's skin condition
skin_condition = input "Does skin appear normal? (Y/N)"

if skin_condition = N then
    output "check pulse, call doctor"
endif
    respiratory_status = input "Is the paitent breathing normally? (Y/N)"

// checking the patient's respiratory staus

if respiratory_status = N then
    output "check for obstructions, call doctor"
endif
    temperature = input "What is the patients body temperature?"

// checking the patient's body temperature

if temperature < 95 then
    output "add additional blankets to warm patient"
endif
    neurological_status = input "Can the patient move or respond? (Y/N)"

// checking the patient's neurological status

if neurological_status = N then
    output "check consciousness, call doctor"
endif
    cardiovascular_status = input "Does the patient have a normal pulse rate? (Y/N)"

// checking the patient's cardiovascular status

if cardiovascular_status = N then
    output "check consciousness, call doctor"
endif
    output "monitor patient every hour or as necessary"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the general idea. Just a couple of points:

1. You never set `skin_condition` prior to using it.
2. You're asking for inputs before they're required in the flowchart (e.g. respiratory_status). Ask the question when you get to that point in the chart.

Comment: I did set skin_condition I just forgot to copy & paste it thank you for making me realise haha. I've made some changes: `// skin condition
skin_condition = input "Does skin appear normal? (Y/N)"

if skin_condition = N then
    output "check pulse, call doctor"
endif

output respiratory_status
   
// respiratory staus
respiratory_status = input "Is the paitent breathing normally? (Y/N)"

if respiratory_status = N then
    output "check for obstructions, call doctor"
endif

output temperature` can't paste the whole thing but this gives the idea

Comment: I suggest you **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include your updated information.

Comment: thank you, just done this - opinions on where I should go from there or anything I can add to make the psuedocode more interesting?

Comment: The lines which say e.g. "output respiratory_status", "output neurological_status" before you've obtained those values should probably be eliminated. But I have no ideas about how to make pseudocode (or real code, for that matter) "interesting".

Comment: I have made another edit which takes into consideration what you have said, would it work like this?

Comment: You have written `output respiratory_status = input "Is the paitent breathing normally? (Y/N)"`. I don't think the word `output` is appropriate here. I suggest saying something like `respiratory_status = input "Is the paitent breathing normally? (Y/N)"`. This is just an example - there are several places similar to this in your pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have made another edit - would this work in line with the flowchart?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest getting more detail than just "skin condition". The flowchart specifically asks for "colour" and "collateral circulation". Respiratory status seems to consist of "airway patency", "lung sounds", "rate", "rhythm", and "depth of respiration". And so forth for the other conditions. The pseudocode should probably gather all this information.